# Django- why after using ajax, it becomes an empty page

Tags: python, ajax, django

The function on the page:

- user enter some information on the form
- without refreshing, the right side can show some query result(sales) based on user entry

Before adding the ajax function, the page can display the form and the table. But after using the ajax, the page becomes empty.

Can anyone help check what is the reason? Thanks in advance.

**url**

```
url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='result'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Input(models.Model):
    company=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region=models.CharField(max_length=100)   

class Result(models.Model):
    sales=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
```

**views.py**

from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.core import serializers

```
class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Result.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if self.request.is_ajax():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region).aggregate(Sum('sales'))
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(queryset))

        else:
             return HttpResponse(form.errors)

    '''def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))'''
```

**html**

```
<style>...CSS part
</style>

<script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#InputForm").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    var region= $("#id_region").val();
    var company= $("#id_company").val();

        $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('post'),
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "dupont_list/",
        success: function(data) {
        var html = "<table>"
        html += "<td>"+data['sales__sum']+"</td>"
        html += "</table>"
        $("#result").html(html);

            html += "</table>"
            $("#result").html(html);
        }   
        return false;
    });
})
</script>

<form id="InputForm" method="post" action="">   #here is the data entry form
        {% csrf_token %}

        <!--enter the company name--> 
        <div class="field">
            {{ form.company.errors }}
            <label id="id_company" name="company" for="{{ form.company.id_for_label }}">Company:</label>
            {{ form.company }}
        </div>

        <!--select region-->
        <div class="field" >
            <label> Select the Region:
            {{ form.region }}
                {% for region in form.region.choices %}
                     <option value="region" name= "region" id="id_region">{{region}} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </label>
        </div>

        <!--submit-->
        <p><input type="button" value="Submit" /></p></div>
    </form> 
</div>

    <div id="result" class="result">   <!--Showing the filtered result in database-->
    <table>
    <tr><b>Sales</b></tr>
    <td> {{sales.sales__sum}}</td>

    <tr><b>Employee</b></tr>
    <td> {{employee.employee__sum}}</td>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a `FormView`:

```
class ResultView(FormView):

    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    form_class = InputForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["results"] = Result.objects.all()
        context["sales"] = context.results.aggregate(Sum('sales'))
        return context

    def form_valid(self,form):
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']
        queryset = Result.objects.filter(region=region).aggregate(Sum('sales'))
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(queryset))
```

This way you're bypassing the `get_context_data` and `get_queryset` methods if the form is valid and return a custom content response.

Comment: Hi@Sebastian Wozny, thanks a lot~~but still an empty page, do you think there is anything wrong in my html?

Comment: I think I forgot to return the context. Try now.

Comment: Also use the developer tools in your browser to inspect the network requests, and what the server is returning.

Comment: It is returning "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."  I have set "async: true," in success, but error still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93148/discussion-between-sebastian-wozny-and-elena).